# параметр MAX_FILE_SIZE можно установить програмно?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Всем привет,
Подключив файл 'simple_html_dom.php';
я передаю в функцию str_get_html($html_code)
содержимое файла в 667 KiB  и получаю false 
лезу в код этой функции и вижу ограничение

```
if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
{
```

И MAX_FILE_SIZE выводит 600000 то есть больше моего файла

В моем локальном php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 400M
```

Так тоже не помогает:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '400M');
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
```

Этот параметр MAX_FILE_SIZE можно установить програмно или как-то побороть это ограничение?

Спасибо!

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы пытаетесь что-то распарсить. Если так, то почему бы не использовать DOMDocument и XPath.

Answer (score 2):

В коде:

```
if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
```

Это ваша локальная функция, это она установила данное значение, закоментируйте, или же найдите где у вас в коде объявляется данная константа `MAX_FILE_SIZE` и смените её значение